# How to style a checkbox nested within a label tag

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I usually use the following when setting up a checkbox:

```
<input ....>
<label for="...">Lorem ipsum</label>
```

I use the standard method of styling label::before to simulate a style for my checkbox depending on whether the checkbox has been checked or not:

```
input label{....}
input::checked label{....}
```

However, a Wordpress plugin is forcing me to use the following syntax:

```
<label>....
    <input....>
</label>
```

As CSS in unable to traverse the DOM, my usual pure CSS method won't work here.

Any other suggestions? Perhaps jQuery? Or is there a pure CSS solution I'm missing?

Comment: You'll need to use JS for that HTML structure, as CSS cannot go up the DOM. Only horizontally or downwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do it with CSS, since it can't traverse the DOM (as you mentioned yourself).
Unfortunately `label:checked` doesn't work either.

So you are looking for a JS/jQuery solution:

```js
$(function() {
  $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':checked') );
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.active {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

There might be situations where the label is before the input... Then I advice to use the `for` attribute, to make sure the label is related to the input, the code should then be:

```js
$(function() {
  $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('label[for='+ $(this).attr('id') + ']' ).toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':checked') );
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.active {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="idforcheckbox">This is the label</label>
<input id="idforcheckbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use JS for that. CSS can't handle parents. Have a look at this jQuery code:

```js
$(document).on('click','input[type="checkbox"]',function() {
  if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it actually demonstrated a visible change based on the checkbox' checked status.

Answer (score 0):

This CAN now be done with only CSS:

```
label:has(input:checked) {
  /* styles for labels that have a nested checked input */
}
```

Use the above selector to style the "checked" input(s).

For the "unchecked" input(s) style the label element

```
label {
  /* styles for labels that have a nested unchecked input */
}
```

or, for more specificity

```
label:not(:has(input:checked)) {
  /* styles for labels that have a nested unchecked input */
}
```